# Change MongoDb ObjectId _id to string in Micronaut using java

Tags: java, micronaut, mongo-java, micronaut-data, reactive-mongo-java

I have below Pojo class for the mongo entity

```
public class Product {
    @BsonProperty("_id")
    @BsonId
    private ObjectId id;
    private String name;
    private float price;
    private String description;
}
```

when I fetch the mongo result as per the below code

```
var item = Flowable.fromPublisher(this.repository.getCollection("product", Product.class).find()).blockingIterable();
```

The id id mapped something like this

[image]

However, in the database the id is something like this

[image]

How do I map this id in the correct way, I am using Micronaut framework with java 15

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid looks correct to me. If you want to achieve the same, i gues you shoult try that: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mongodb/bson/2.7.2/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html#toStringMongod()

Comment: value.toString() does work for me.